# What is module aes-i586?

Tags: linux-mint, lvm, luks, aes, modprobe

I'm using LMDE4 with LVM on LUKS and recently I've been getting these cryptic error messages at boot:

```
modprobe: module aes-i586 not found in modules.dep
    Volume group "lvmlmde" not found
    Cannot process volume group lvmlmde
    Volume group "lvmlmde" not found
    Cannot process volume group lvmlmde
Please unlock disk lvmlmde:
```

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1               8:1    0   976M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0 237,5G  0 part  
  └─lvmlmde        254:0    0 237,5G  0 crypt 
    ├─lvmlmde-root 254:1    0 233,6G  0 lvm   /
    └─lvmlmde-swap 254:2    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sr0                 11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

`dmesg` output:

```
[    2.855596] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.871879] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.871881] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.874372] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:093A:2510.0001/input/input4
[    2.874471] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
[    2.924727] random: cryptsetup: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    3.418045] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    3.446521] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    3.623109] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input3
[    3.640559] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=2016, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    3.640562] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.640564] usb 5-2: Product: Biometric Coprocessor
[    3.640565] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[    5.607628] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[    5.621228] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    5.776410] random: cryptsetup: uninitialized urandom read (2 bytes read)
[    5.805509] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    5.863363] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    6.098499] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  3154 MB/s
[    6.166494] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  3673 MB/s
[    6.234490] raid6: sse2x2   gen()  3733 MB/s
[    6.302489] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  4477 MB/s
[    6.370496] raid6: sse2x4   gen()  6627 MB/s
[    6.438491] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  4920 MB/s
[    6.438492] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 6627 MB/s
[    6.438493] raid6: .... xor() 4920 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    6.438494] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[    6.450339] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    6.486485]    prefetch64-sse:  8278.000 MB/sec
[    6.526485]    generic_sse:  7359.000 MB/sec
[    6.526486] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (8278.000 MB/sec)
[    6.610533] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic
[    6.805887] PM: Image not found (code -22)
[    7.038907] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    7.384848] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    7.421604] systemd[1]: systemd 241 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    7.438602] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    7.443937] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <jenny>.
[    7.596112] urandom_read: 1 callbacks suppressed
[    7.596113] random: lvmconfig: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)
[    7.669929] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.681009] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/thinkfan.service:8: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/thinkfan.pid → /run/thinkfan.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    7.709742] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.709836] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    7.710017] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    7.712150] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dcryptsetup.slice.
[    7.712313] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    7.712349] systemd[1]: systemd-journald-dev-log.socket: Socket service systemd-journald.service not loaded, refusing.
[    7.712468] systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    7.730955] systemd[336]: ufw.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.734301] systemd[337]: kmod-static-nodes.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.737629] systemd[338]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.745118] systemd[339]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.755713] systemd[343]: keyboard-setup.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.756324] systemd[344]: lvm2-monitor.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.756404] systemd[341]: blk-availability.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.774922] systemd[347]: systemd-udev-trigger.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.813159] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    7.813240] systemd-modules-load[338]: Inserted module 'lp'
[    7.820409] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    7.836410] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    7.836484] systemd-modules-load[338]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
[    7.841470] systemd[357]: systemd-random-seed.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.852010] systemd-modules-load[338]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
[    7.852539] systemd[356]: systemd-sysusers.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.859573] systemd[359]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.869308] systemd[360]: systemd-udev-trigger.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.923654] systemd[361]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    7.946678] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946693] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946707] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:3] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946722] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:4] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.946738] systemd-tmpfiles[361]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:5] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/log → /run/speech-dispatcher/log; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    7.963453] systemd[363]: systemd-udevd.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.214213] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input5
[    8.214420] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID]
[    8.214513] input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input6
[    8.214528] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    8.214627] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input7
[    8.214640] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    8.228735] ACPI: Video Device [VID1] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    8.273369] acpi device:07: registered as cooling_device2
[    8.273469] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:06/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8
[    8.273571] ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
[    8.313757] battery: ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    8.335545] tpm_tis 00:05: 1.2 TPM (device-id 0xFFFF, rev-id 255)
[    8.343376] tpm tpm0: [Hardware Error]: Adjusting reported timeouts: A 10000->10000us B 10000->10000us C 0->752000us D 0->752000us
[    8.382609] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    8.392741] systemd-udevd[380]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
[    8.412527] intel_rng: FWH not detected
[    8.443791] systemd-udevd[380]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
[    8.471666] leds_ss4200: no LED devices found
[    8.471720] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.26
[    8.471721] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/
[    8.471722] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS 7CETC6WW (2.16 ), EC 7CHT21WW-1.09
[    8.471723] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad R60, model 9461DXG
[    8.471725] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: Outdated ThinkPad BIOS/EC firmware
[    8.471725] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: This firmware may be missing critical bug fixes and/or important features
[    8.471801] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
[    8.471881] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    8.485006] thinkpad_acpi: radio switch found; radios are disabled
[    8.485029] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
[    8.485030] thinkpad_acpi: Disabling thinkpad-acpi brightness events by default...
[    8.508267] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is blocked
[    8.531558] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
[    8.536531] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
[    8.536643] iTCO_wdt: Found a ICH7-M or ICH7-U TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x1060)
[    8.538853] iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
[    8.554149] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: CardBus bridge found [17aa:202f]
[    8.554175] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: Using INTVAL to route CSC interrupts to PCI
[    8.554177] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: Routing CardBus interrupts to PCI
[    8.554184] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: TI: mfunc 0x01001b22, devctl 0x64
[    8.564506] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface available, not loading native one
[    8.564611] thinkpad_acpi: Console audio control enabled, mode: monitor (read only)
[    8.574886] thinkpad_acpi: battery 1 registered (start 0, stop 0)
[    8.574893] battery: new extension: ThinkPad Battery Extension
[    8.574950] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input9
[    8.656068] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: probe_mask set to 0x1 for device 17aa:2010
[    8.707378] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for AD1981: line_outs=1 (0x5/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    8.707382] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.707384] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    8.707385] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    8.707387] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0xa/0x0
[    8.707389] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    8.707391] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x8
[    8.707393] snd_hda_codec_analog hdaudioC0D0:      CD=0x19
[    8.793419] systemd-udevd[383]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
[    8.795362] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: ISA IRQ mask 0x0cf8, PCI irq 16
[    8.795366] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: Socket status: 30000086
[    8.795373] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [io  0x9000-0xcfff]
[    8.795375] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [mem 0xe4300000-0xe7ffffff]
[    8.795378] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xe4300000-0xe7ffffff:
[    8.795381]  excluding 0xe4300000-0xe46cffff
[    8.795390] yenta_cardbus 0000:15:00.0: pcmcia: parent PCI bridge window: [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff 64bit pref]
[    8.795392] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff:
[    8.795396]  excluding 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff
[    8.830197] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[    8.898636] systemd[535]: systemd-cryptsetup@lvmlmde.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.900699] systemd[534]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-da7fb045\x2d11e5\x2d45f6\x2d8a2d\x2d394d10e2ffaa.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    8.919387] systemd-cryptsetup[535]: Volume lvmlmde already active.
[    8.939867] systemd[538]: systemd-fsckd.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.035898] systemd[546]: boot.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.051318] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    9.065593] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[    9.097427] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state available
[    9.139815] systemd[570]: lvm2-pvscan@254:0.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.337821] systemd[605]: dev-mapper-lvmlmde\x2dswap.swap: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.351630] Adding 4124668k swap on /dev/mapper/lvmlmde-swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4124668k SSFS
[    9.391555] systemd[611]: tmp.mount: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.403988] systemd[613]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.409619] systemd[614]: apparmor.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.411364] systemd[616]: console-setup.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.428075] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:1] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428136] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:2] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428194] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:3] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428251] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:4] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher → /run/speech-dispatcher/.cache/speech-dispatcher; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.428312] systemd-tmpfiles[613]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/speech-dispatcher.conf:5] Line references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/speech-dispatcher/log → /run/speech-dispatcher/log; please update the tmpfiles.d/ drop-in file accordingly.
[    9.483358] random: crng init done
[    9.508355] systemd[632]: systemd-update-utmp.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.510899] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.304:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=627 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.519694] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.312:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=628 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.519697] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.312:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=628 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.527472] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.320:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=634 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.527474] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.320:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=634 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.531209] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.324:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=633 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.531214] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.324:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=633 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.531215] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.324:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=633 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.538469] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.328:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=635 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.543954] audit: type=1400 audit(1617986458.336:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="torbrowser_tor" pid=636 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.623815] systemd[659]: networking.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.647406] systemd[667]: alsa-state.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.649745] systemd[668]: mintsystem.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.654008] systemd[670]: upower.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.668284] systemd[664]: acpi-support.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.668450] systemd[671]: ksm.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.671811] systemd[674]: systemd-logind.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.673339] systemd[672]: thinkfan.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.673535] systemd[673]: mytaskkiller.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.677814] systemd[675]: irqbalance.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.706962] systemd[678]: dbus.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.707338] systemd[679]: NetworkManager.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.708147] systemd[681]: lm-sensors.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.715154] systemd[687]: udisks2.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.717439] systemd[683]: debian-system-adjustments.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[    9.785237] systemd-udevd[391]: Process '/usr/sbin/tlp auto' failed with exit code 4.
[    9.802089] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event6 (Power Button)
[    9.818158] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[    9.818160] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[    9.818161] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
[    9.818257] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    9.831951] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x0c0000-0x0fffff:
[    9.831960]  excluding 0xc0000-0xcffff 0xdc000-0xfffff
[    9.831994] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff:
[    9.832006]  excluding 0xa0000000-0xa0ffffff
[    9.832031] pcmcia_socket pcmcia_socket0: cs: memory probe 0x60000000-0x60ffffff:
[    9.832043]  excluding 0x60000000-0x60ffffff
[    9.874853] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[    9.874858] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[    9.895423] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (Lid Switch)
[    9.895732] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (Sleep Button)
[    9.895995] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
[    9.896315] systemd-logind[674]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event8 (ThinkPad Extra Buttons)
[    9.914258] systemd-logind[674]: New seat seat0.
[   10.041402] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   10.062334] systemd-udevd[383]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
[   10.073913] systemd-udevd[383]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
[   10.088059] iwl3945 0000:03:00.0 wls3: renamed from wlan0
[   10.131633] systemd[742]: lm-sensors.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.264099] systemd[782]: clamav-freshclam.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.264275] systemd[779]: systemd-user-sessions.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.311618] systemd[788]: polkit.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.339792] systemd[794]: lightdm.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.374775] systemd[797]: lightdm.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.534983] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   10.548440] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV515 0x1002:0x7145 0x17AA:0x2006 0x00).
[   10.551249] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000d0000-0x000d3fff window]
[   10.551258] caller pci_map_rom+0x6a/0x1b0 mapping multiple BARs
[   10.551354] ATOM BIOS: M64CSP/M62CSP/M54CSP/M52CSP
[   10.551385] [drm] Generation 2 PCI interface, using max accessible memory
[   10.551392] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 128M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x0000000007FFFFFF (128M used)
[   10.551395] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 512M 0x0000000008000000 - 0x0000000027FFFFFF
[   10.551419] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=128M, BAR=128M
[   10.551420] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR
[   10.554668] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 1536476 kiB
[   10.554670] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   10.554676] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   10.554713] [drm] radeon: 128M of VRAM memory ready
[   10.554715] [drm] radeon: 512M of GTT memory ready.
[   10.554740] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 131072, num gpu pages 131072
[   10.592359] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[   10.608079] [drm] radeon: 1 quad pipes, 1 z pipes initialized.
[   10.661707] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[   10.743546] systemd[833]: tlp.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   10.863722] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): ens2: link is not ready
[   10.907159] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wls3: link is not ready
[   10.940335] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[   10.940370] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   10.940375] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000008000000 and cpu addr 0x0000000070cf6855
[   10.940378] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   10.940379] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   10.940381] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   10.940399] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   10.940419] [drm] Loading R500 Microcode
[   10.987459] radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/R520_cp.bin
[   10.987854] [drm] radeon: ring at 0x0000000008001000
[   10.987898] [drm] ring test succeeded in 3 usecs
[   11.000629] systemd[881]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   11.019256] [drm] ib test succeeded in 0 usecs
[   11.033946] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   11.033948] [drm] Connector 0:
[   11.033949] [drm]   VGA-1
[   11.033951] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[   11.033951] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033952] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   11.033953] [drm] Connector 1:
[   11.033954] [drm]   LVDS-1
[   11.033956] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e60 0x7e60 0x7e64 0x7e64 0x7e68 0x7e68 0x7e6c 0x7e6c
[   11.033956] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033957] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_LVTM1
[   11.033958] [drm] Connector 2:
[   11.033958] [drm]   SVIDEO-1
[   11.033959] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033960] [drm]     TV1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC2
[   11.033961] [drm] Connector 3:
[   11.033961] [drm]   DVI-I-1
[   11.033962] [drm]   HPD1
[   11.033963] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[   11.033964] [drm]   Encoders:
[   11.033965] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_TMDS1
[   11.112019] systemd-udevd[402]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
[   11.443338] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD80C0000
[   11.443340] [drm] vram apper at 0xD8000000
[   11.443341] [drm] size 5914624
[   11.443342] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   11.443343] [drm]    pitch is 5632
[   11.443850] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   11.509339] thinkpad_ec: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   11.509408] thinkpad_ec: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.509958] thinkpad_ec: thinkpad_ec 0.43 loaded.
[   11.512389] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 175x65
[   11.513042] tp_smapi 0.43 loading...
[   11.514946] tp_smapi successfully loaded (smapi_port=0xb2).
[   11.517590] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   11.534622] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[   11.704378] systemd[792]: getty@tty1.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   13.212024] systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 119.
[   13.213859] systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/119...
[   13.214981] systemd[1191]: user-runtime-dir@119.service: Failed to connect stdout to the journal socket, ignoring: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know this error and what might be causing it?

Comment: What caused it?  Sort of.. that module used to be sitting in a known location using /dev/sdX type assignments.  Without that (crypto) module, your boot loader can't decrypt and boot into lvmlde..   For some reason, the assignments probably changed.. like removing an extra hard disk or changing partitions.  How to fix it?  :(  Not a clue.  The cause is explained well [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=319432).. but again.. not a clue.  Hopefully some brainiac will come along that does. :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thx, I read that thread. But I think I know where to look now... Cya

Answer (score 0):

On the question "What is module aes-i586?" I guess it's the AES implementation optimized for Intel "586" CPUs, because `modinfo aes-x86_64` outputs:

```text
...
alias:          crypto-aes-asm
alias:          aes-asm
alias:          crypto-aes
alias:          aes
license:        GPL
description:    Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, asm optimized
...
```